# How to use "required" on html form? Required="required" not working

Tags: html, xml, validation, requiredfieldvalidator, required-field

I created a form, but I'm not sure why the field for the required attribute doesn't work. I'm using xml, hmtl and jquery. I've tried many options, including:

```
<label class="control-labels form-required" t-att-for="'author_'+widget.id">AUTORE*</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="author" t-att-id="'author_'+widget.id" t-att-value="widget.author" required="required"/>
```

and

```
<label class="control-labels form-required" t-att-for="'author_'+widget.id">AUTORE*</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="author" t-att-id="'author_'+widget.id" t-att-value="widget.author" required/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just simply put `required`? that is sufficient enough no need to set it equal to anything and it should work. doc is here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: @Adriana, you should put any code in your question. The comments are not meant to contain blocks of code.

Answer (score 0):

From [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) documentation

**Definition and Usage**

The *required* attribute is a *boolean* attribute.

When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

Note: The required attribute works with the following input types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, date pickers, number, checkbox, radio, and file.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```